# How can I use a variable to refer to a column of a row in an SSIS Script?

Tags: ssis

EDIT: I'm closing this and posting again with a  better description.

I'm loading some medical diagnoses from a flat file into a staging table. Each diagnosis has three fields:  Diagnosis_Code, Diagnosis_Date, and Diagnosis_Type. The file contains a total of 9 diagnoses, for a total of 27 fields (Diagnosis01_Date, Diagnosis02_Date, etc..) the field names in the staging table match the field names in the file.

Using a script component, I need to perform functions on some of these values and would like to do it in a loop, instead of writing the same thing 9 times. If I were working with a recordset in VB, I'd write something like this in in the Input0_ProcessInputRow sub:

```
For i = 1 to 9
   row.("Diagnosis0"+ i +"_Date").Value = diagnosisDate 
next i
```

But the columns of a row aren't a collection and I can't find a way to refer to them by name. Is there a way to loop through the columns and modify them in an SSIS script?

edit: what I want to do is, inside my script component, replace this series of repetitive assignments:.

```
row.Diagnosis01 = diagnosisDate
row.Diagnosis02 = diagnosisDate
....
row.Diagnosis09 = diagnosisDate
```

With a loop.

Comment: How you would do it depends on the data. Is it delimited? Fixed-width?

Comment: The data is pipe-delimited.

Comment: Can you include a sample of the data? Also, is this a Script Component in a Data Flow Task, or a Script Task? What is the outcome/output of the task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve this, reading the file one line at a time:

```
string line = row; // 'row' will be a line of data from your file

string[] fields = line.Split('|');

for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
{
    // perform whatever logic you need to on fields[i]
}
```

Comment: Right now, my script component is using the Input0_ProcessInputRow  sub, which is processing the rows one at a time and setting the values there: row.Dx1= myDate, row.Dx2 = myDate...Where do I apply this approach?

Comment: I just added an edit to clarify what I"m tryng to do, if that helps.